# JavaScript preprocessor

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a JavaScript preprocessor. Or maybe compiler. Or "transpiler". I don't know what the right word. It's for transforming JavaScript code in the same way that the C preprocessor transforms C code: substitution of macros/placeholders, configurable output, getting the names of functions that code is contained within, and so on.

These are the requirements (some are optional but preferred):

- It must be able to stringify parameters like in C.
- It should preferably be able to get the function name from inside something like this (the syntax is something I'm making up for this example):

  this.myFunc = function () {
      return @@FUNC_NAME@@; // Would substitute in "myFunc"
  };
- It should preferably be able to substitute in the name of an object's constructor function inside its methods:

  function F (x) {
    this.constructorName = @@...@@; // The ellipsis is just a placeholder for some way of traversing up nested structures like these
  }
- It should be run using JavaScript code. Babel and gulp do this, so compilation/preprocessing/whatever would be invoked by executing, say, `babel.preprocess("path-to-file")`. On top of that, build configuration files for these systems are also written in JavaScript. This needlessly complicates a project. I can't make sense of the JavaScript libraries that have files like `package.json` or `bower.js`, and I can't tell where the build system code ends and the application code begins.

Comment: Maybe the "*transformers*" feature of [RollupJS](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#transformers), or a plugin can do this, but I have never used Rollup (but I remember it from "See Also" section of a Webpack tutorial). Rollup is a module bundler, built for a different purpose but maybe you can make it work for you in principle.